# How to convert cUrl code to drupal way?

Tags: 8

I have below code

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);
```

In Drupal 8 way we can use

```
$client = \Drupal::httpClient();

$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
  // To add 
]);
```

Not sure how to pass needed parameters/convert it to drupal way.

**[UPDATE]**

```
$uri = 'http://domain.com';

$client = \Drupal::httpClient();

$actual_uri = NULL;
$response = $client->fromOptions([
    'allow_redirects' => [
      'on_redirect' => function (RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface $uri) use (&$actual_uri) {
        $actual_uri = (string) $uri;
      }
    ],
  ])->send($request);

dump($response);
exit;
```

Answer (score 4):

The only special thing I see there is getting the effective URL, which is actually something that was specifically added back to Guzzle 6 for Drupal: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/1166

See \Drupal\aggregator\Plugin\aggregator\fetcher\DefaultFetcher::fetch:

```
  /** @var \Psr\Http\Message\UriInterface $actual_uri */
  $actual_uri = NULL;
  $response = $this->httpClientFactory->fromOptions([
    'allow_redirects' => [
      'on_redirect' => function (RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, UriInterface $uri) use (&$actual_uri) {
        $actual_uri = (string) $uri;
      }
    ],
  ])->send($request);
```

Comment: Gives `InvalidArgumentException: URI must be a string or UriInterface in GuzzleHttp\Psr7\uri_for() `. Passing my URL in `$request`

Comment: well, what is your $url? apparently it's not a string which would not have worked for curl either

Comment: Update your question with your updated code

Comment: I have added code in question

Comment: your code snippet doesn't show where $request is coming from, fromOptions() is also called on the factory, which is a separate service. Have a look at the full method of the class I mentioned